# File attachments should be private if node is unpublished

Tags: 8, files

If a content editor uploads a file to an unpublished node. An anonymous user should not be able to go to the file by the url pathing UNTIL the node is published. Any help on how to restrict file attachment access to anonymous users on unpublished nodes would be appreciated.

Comment: These were public files to start out with?